# What is code p2647 for 2000 camaro z28

Tags: chevrolet, dtc, camaro, code, valve-lifter

I have code P2647 on a 2000 Camaro Z28.

What is this code and what is the fix for this code?

The engine is making a loud lifter noise when starting.

Comment: I know you have looked at it and read it but can you reverify the code.  Three different code guides including my snapon's show P2647 as unique for a HONDA (rocker arm actuator).  The LS1 does not have this type of valve train.

Comment: Please re verify the code you posted.

Comment: I'm curious what ever came of this. The list of codes your car is capable of doesn't even contain anything that looks like you might have typo'd as P2647. The closest I can find is P0467, which indicates an issue with the evap purge system, which would definitely not make a loud lifter noise when starting (unless the "lifter noise" was the evap solenoid going nuts?).